# Is there a way to access a laravel valet app from another device?

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I'm trying to connect to access my laravel app from a another device on the same network. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give access to everyone to your app by using

```
valet share
```

If you want to access it only locally, you can edit you hosts file on your other device and bind the valet URL to your first computer ip

```
192.168.1.19 laravel.dev
```

You just have to check if your computer allow remote access.

BTW the valet share command is way more easier :)

Comment: don't just simply type 'valet share', also add the site-name of the site you want to share to the command (i had to figure that out first so maybe this comment will help someone)

Answer (score 2):

use `Valet share`

However this only works if you are not serving the app via https using `valet secure`.

After running `valet share`, a URL that looks like "2jd437s.ngrok.io" will be generated. And that's what you will use to visit your app remotely.

To cancel, use `Ctrl+c`

Comment: Valet share now works with HTTPS too! https://github.com/laravel/valet/pull/630

Answer (score 0):

Hope, it will help someone as I've wasted my 1 day to complete this simple heck.

**My Goal was:** Share my localhost URL as https with external service like Paypal, Stripe.

**Steps:**
My Local URL is: `yourdomain.test`

**Step 1:** First secure my local url to enable `https`:

```sh
valet secure yourdomain.test
```

**Step 2:** Next Share my `localhost` to outside of the internet:

```sh
valet share https://yourdomain.test
```

Booooom. Now, You'll get an `ngrock` URL and that would be pretty awesomely work like this - https://1bba-103-108-147-143.ngrok.io . [Click this URL to browser and you'll able to access your localhost from outside]

> Note: This ngrock URL would work upto 2 hour by default. So to solve
> this please create an ngrock account -

1. Download ngrock on local - https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup
2. Validate Your ngrock in localhost terminal with authtoken - https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken

Great, now again share your localhost URL -

```
valet share https://yourdomain.test
```

It will available on the internet if your local stay alive, there is no time limitation now.

Comment: For Wordpress sites to keep url permanently - `./ngrok http -host-header=rewrite wp.wedevs.test`